# How can I move my navigation links from top of the page to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I basically want to keep the nav with all of its contents at the top of the HTML, but have it moved to the bottom of the page with CSS as I am doing mobile-first approach and want the navigation to appear at the top when I resize it to tablet or laptop. I tried using minus with bottom tag but it takes forever to get it to the bottom and does not seem to be the most efficient way to do it. Is the only way to move the context to the bottom of the page is to put it at the bottom of HTML file or is there a completely different way I should approach this?

This is what I have at the moment:

[image]

I want to move the underlined links to the bottom, my code:

```css
#topnavigationmenu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="mainpage">
        <nav id="topnavigationmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"> example </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> example </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> example </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: You mean like to the very bottom or after the text in the image? hard to understand what you want.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The easiest solution:** You can create two instances of `<nav>` and show one on mobile and on desktop using media queries.

**Possibly better solution**: You can use Flexbox (and even CSS Grid I guess) to change the order, so let's say inside the `mainpage` div you have two sections the `nav` and a `div` with your page content:

```
<nav id="topnavigationmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> example </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> example </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> example </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="page-content">
 <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

You can add `display:flex;` to `mainpage` and manipulate the order these appear on mobile vs desktop/tablet using media queries.

I'd suggest checking these articles out:

[Ordering Flex Items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

[A Complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)